# how to sort a datagridview by 2 columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I sort a DataGridView by two columns (ascending)? I have two columns: `day` and `status`.

If I need to sort by one column, I do:

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort (this.dataGridView1.Columns["day"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

But for two?

Comment: i dont think you can sort them both together, you can call your code for 2 columns to order it by day first, and by another column later

Comment: you can have a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/7f819d92-5bd9-4b5b-b08c-fb15bb5331c4/

Comment: Are you using WinForms or something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your `DataGridView` is databound, you can sort your `Datatable` view and rebind to datatable as below:

```
private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Bind the DataGridView to the BindingSource        
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
    SortDataByMultiColumns(); //Sort the Data
}

private void SortDataByMultiColumns()
{
    DataView view = dataTable1.DefaultView;
    view.Sort = "day ASC, status DESC"; 
    bindingSource1.DataSource = view; //rebind the data source
}
```

OR, without using bindingsource and binding directly to `DataView`:

```
private void SortDataByMultiColumns()
{
    DataView view = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    view.Sort = "day ASC, status DESC"; 
    dataGridView1.DataSource = view; //rebind the data source
}
```

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: @user1112847 I dont understand..if u r asking if inplace of bindingSource1 your ds.Tables[0] code will work fine then yes, I think so it should  work fine..

Answer (score 9):

Add a hidden column that combines the two and sort by that.

Comment: It is a good idea but wont work if you want to sort one column asc and another desc.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the DataGridView's Sort method, but specify an argument that is an instance of a class that implements IComparer.

Here is an example of such a class:

```
public class MyTwoColumnComparer : System.Collections.IComparer
{
    private string _SortColumnName1;
    private int _SortOrderMultiplier1;
    private string _SortColumnName2;
    private int _SortOrderMultiplier2;

    public MyTwoColumnComparer(string pSortColumnName1, SortOrder pSortOrder1, string pSortColumnName2, SortOrder pSortOrder2)
    {
        _SortColumnName1 = pSortColumnName1;
        _SortOrderMultiplier1 = (pSortOrder1 == SortOrder.Ascending) ? 1 : -1;
        _SortColumnName2 = pSortColumnName2;
        _SortOrderMultiplier2 = (pSortOrder2 == SortOrder.Ascending) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        DataGridViewRow r1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
        DataGridViewRow r2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

        int iCompareResult = _SortOrderMultiplier1 * String.Compare(r1.Cells[_SortColumnName1].Value.ToString(), r2.Cells[_SortColumnName1].Value.ToString());
        if (iCompareResult == 0) iCompareResult = _SortOrderMultiplier2 * String.Compare(r1.Cells[_SortColumnName2].Value.ToString(), r2.Cells[_SortColumnName2].Value.ToString());
        return iCompareResult;
    }
}
```

Now, we might call this from a column whose SortMode is 'Programmatic' on a mouse click:

```
private void dgvAllMyEmployees_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn dgvcClicked = dgvAllEmployees.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (dgvcClicked.SortMode == DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic)
    {
        _SortOrder = (_SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending) ? SortOrder.Descending : SortOrder.Ascending;
        MyTwoColumnComparer Sort2C = new MyTwoColumnComparer(dgvcClicked.Name, _SortOrder, "LastName", SortOrder.Ascending);
        dgvAllEmployees.Sort(Sort2C);
    }
}
```

The class level variable _SortOrder helps keep track of which order to go in. One can enhance this more to remember the last two columns clicked and sort on them in the desired order.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: On second thought... I can't get this to work.  It sorts the first time I click on a column, (ascending) but it won't sort descending if I click on it again

Comment: This answer got me SO CLOSE!! I added a new answer that builds on this answer and solves the problem of a column not being to toggle between Ascending and Descending when clicking on it.

Comment: Looked very promising, but unfortunately it appears this doesn't work with data bound datagridview controls.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR; I have a two-line solution.**

I had to do the same thing, but after researching all these complicated ways to do this by either including a separate .dll or writing my own class/methods, I knew there had to be an easier way. It turns out I was right because I figured out how to accomplish this with using only two lines of code. This worked for me.

Luckily, it turns out for us that the .NET Framework Sort() method does help us with this. The idea is that you want to sort the columns individually, but the order in which you sort them in is what will produce the desired output.

So, as an example, I have a column for file type and a column for a file name. Whenever I want to sort the data by the types, I want to make sure that the names are also sorted within each type shown.

**GOAL:** Sorting by type will also sort the file names alphabetically.

**Data:**

> zxcv.css
>
> testimg3.jpg
>
> asdf.html
>
> testimg2.jpg
>
> testimg1.jpg

**Sorting data by name:**

```
mConflictsDataGridView.Sort(mConflictsDataGridView.Columns[mNameLabel.Index], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

> asdf.html
>
> testimg1.jpg
>
> testimg2.jpg
>
> testimg3.jpg
>
> zxcv.css

As you can see, this will name sure that the names will be sorted accordingly, such that when I now sort by the file types, both requirements will satisfy.

**Sorting data by file type:**

```
mConflictsDataGridView.Sort(mConflictsDataGridView.Columns[mFileExtensionLabel.Index], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

> zxcv.css
>
> asdf.html
>
> testimg1.jpg
>
> testimg2.jpg
>
> testimg3.jpg

Voila! It's sorted!

**SOLUTION:** In your case, you may want to try something like the following, and you may need to tweak it some more to have it cater to your own code.

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns["status"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns["day"], ListSortDirection.Asscending);
```

This should be able to display your results by the day with its status field sorted as well.

Comment: Seems it wont work if there is a value testimg2.css in your example

Comment: this doesn't work. the result is that the grid will be sorted by the last sort operation. the first sort operation is completely obliterated by the second.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that John Kurtz provided got me close. But what I found was the when I clicked on a column once, it did indeed sort by the two columns ... In his example: dgvcClicked.Name, "LastName".  So, good!!

But, if I clicked on the column again, then it would NOT sort by the opposite direction.  So the column became stuck in Ascending.

To overcome this, I had to track the sort order manually.  Started with this class:

```
public class ColumnSorting
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public ListSortDirection Direction { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I added this globally scoped List:

```
List<ColumnSorting> _columnSortingList = new List<ColumnSorting>();
```

Then, in the method that does the Sort, I would

1. Check to see if the column index being sorted already exists in _columnSortingList.  If not, add it.
2. If it already exists, then swap the sort order

And Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/multicolumn_sort.aspx), or use custom sorting:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText =="day")
            {
               myBindingSource.Sort = "day, hour";
            }
        }
```

Comment: dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "day, hour";

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution when working with bound data.  This works for our users, and displays the current sort criteria.  All sorts are only in ascending order.

Add a CheckBox, a TextBox, a ColumnHeaderMouseClick event, and code as shown.  The CheckBox will toggle the TextBox's visibility, and clicking on any column header will add the sort criteria to the TextBox. To clear the TextBox, just double click in it.

```
        private void FooDataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(chkMultiSort.Checked == true)
            {
                string columnHeader = FooDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
                txtMultiSort.Text += (columnHeader + ", ");
                try
                {
                    FooBindingSource.Sort = txtMultiSort.Text.Remove(txtMultiSort.Text.Length - 2);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Sort Data", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
                    txtMultiSort.Text = String.Empty;
                }
            }

        }

        private void ChkMultiSort_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(chkMultiSort.Checked == true)
            {
                txtMultiSort.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                txtMultiSort.Visible = false;
                txtMultiSort.Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void TxtMultiSort_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMultiSort.Text = String.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refinement on the IComparer class from @John Kurtz, which supports mutliple columns and sorting by numbers or dates.

```
    public static void SortOnMultipleColumns(DataGridView dgv, Dictionary<string /*Column Name*/, ColumnSortInfo> sortingColumns)
    {
        // Show the glyphs
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder sortOrder = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.None;

            foreach (var kvp in sortingColumns)
            {
                if (kvp.Key == col.Name)
                {
                    sortOrder = kvp.Value.SortOrder;
                    break;
                }
            }
            col.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = sortOrder;
        }

        // Sort the grid
        MultiColumnCompararor multiColumnCompararor = new MultiColumnCompararor(sortingColumns);
        dgv.Sort(multiColumnCompararor);
    }

    public class ColumnSortInfo
    {
        public enum ValueConversion { ToString, ToNumber, ToDate}
        public ColumnSortInfo(System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder sortOrder, ValueConversion valueConversion = ValueConversion.ToString)
        {
            SortOrder = sortOrder;
            MyValueConversion = valueConversion;
            SortOrderMultiplier = (SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        public System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }
        public int SortOrderMultiplier { get; }
        public ValueConversion MyValueConversion { get; set; }

        public static double StringToDouble(string sVal)
        {
            if (Double.TryParse(sVal, out double dVal))
            {
                return dVal;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public static DateTime StringToDateTime(string sVal)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(sVal, out DateTime dt))
            {
                return dt;
            }
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
    private class MultiColumnCompararor : System.Collections.IComparer
    {

        IDictionary<string /*Column Name*/, ColumnSortInfo> _sortingColumns;

        public MultiColumnCompararor(IDictionary<string /*Column Name*/, ColumnSortInfo> sortingColumns)
        {
            _sortingColumns = sortingColumns;
        }

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            try
            {
                DataGridViewRow r1 = (DataGridViewRow)x;
                DataGridViewRow r2 = (DataGridViewRow)y;

                foreach (var kvp in _sortingColumns)
                {
                    string colName = kvp.Key;
                    ColumnSortInfo csi = kvp.Value;

                    string sVal1 = r1.Cells[colName].Value?.ToString().Trim()??"";
                    string sVal2 = r2.Cells[colName].Value?.ToString().Trim()??"";

                    int iCompareResult = 0;

                    switch (csi.MyValueConversion)
                    {
                        case ColumnSortInfo.ValueConversion.ToString:
                            iCompareResult = String.Compare(sVal1, sVal2);
                            break;
                        case ColumnSortInfo.ValueConversion.ToNumber:
                            double d1 = ColumnSortInfo.StringToDouble(sVal1);
                            double d2 = ColumnSortInfo.StringToDouble(sVal2);
                            iCompareResult = ((d1 == d2) ? 0 : ((d1 > d2) ? 1 : -1));
                            break;
                        case ColumnSortInfo.ValueConversion.ToDate:
                            DateTime dt1 = ColumnSortInfo.StringToDateTime(sVal1);
                            DateTime dt2 = ColumnSortInfo.StringToDateTime(sVal2);
                            iCompareResult = ((dt1 == dt2) ? 0 : ((dt1 > dt2) ? 1 : -1));
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    iCompareResult = csi.SortOrderMultiplier * iCompareResult;

                    if (iCompareResult != 0) { return iCompareResult; }
                }
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
        Dictionary<String, ColumnSortInfo> sortingColumns = new Dictionary<String, ColumnSortInfo>
                        { {"policyNumber", new ColumnSortInfo(System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending)},
                          {"MessageId", new ColumnSortInfo(System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending, ColumnSortInfo.ValueConversion.ToNumber)},
                          {"CreationDate", new ColumnSortInfo(System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending, ColumnSortInfo.ValueConversion.ToDate)}};

        CsUtils.SortOnMultipleColumns(dgv, sortingColumns);
```