# How to Programmatically Sort a DataGridView by Clicking Column Header

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a Windows Form DataGridView that I need to apply custom sorting when a particular column header is clicked, and to reverse the sorting when the column header is clicked again.

I will implement my own sorting algorithm, but I am unclear on how to wire or trigger the column header click with an event, and then keeping track of what was the last sort applied to that column so that I can reverse the sort process.

The data for the DataGridView is being provided through a list, and the rows are being added as `myList.Rows.Add(string_1, string_2, string_3)` to the DataGridView.

Please note that this is not my code, I have just been asked to implement a custom sort for each column.

I have looked online, and have been unsuccessful in finding examples or explanation.

Can anyone provide me with sample code, or point me to a good site that shows a clear example of how to implement this.

Thanks in advance,

Marwan

Comment: Who down voted the OP please leaves some comment to help him do better next time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a solution which works, I bet there are more solutions to find out and hope others will jump in and give you them. You simply add custom code to the `SortCompare` event handler for your `DataGridView` and perform your own Compare function there, this compare function has 2 params and returns -1, 0 or 1:

```
private void dataGridView_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Column == [your desired column]){
     e.Handled = true;
     e.SortResult = Compare(e.CellValue1, e.CellValue2);
   }
}
//Here is my compare function, it simply reverts the normal comparison result
private int Compare(object o1, object o2)
{
   return -o1.ToString().CompareTo(o2.ToString());
}
```

To test it, you simply add 3 rows to a one-column DataGridView such as `a,b,c`. Normally the ascending order (indicated by the up triangle on the ColumnHeader) is `a,b,c` but with the `Compare` function above, it will be `c,b,a` and similarly, the descending order (indicated by the down triangle on the ColumnHeader) is `c,b,a` but with the `Compare` function above, it will be `a,b,c`.

You can add more your own Compare functions and use each one for each Column you like. I think the important thing is how to define these functions, I don't have a clue on why you want to do so because the default comparison is OK.

Comment: I will look at this, and get back to you soon. As for the reason for sorting it is unique to the data being presented in the DataGridView.

Comment: This is not what I had in mind initially, but it ended up working great for what I needed. Thanks so much for taking the time to explain it. It really helped.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've seen such an elegant solution, if i could i would vote +10. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Providing that you use the sorting method in this thread :

[how to sort a datagridview by 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891390/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-by-2-columns)

Here's a simple way to track the latest N columns the user has clicked in correct order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly Stack<int> _stack = new Stack<int>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Column history
            _stack.Push(e.ColumnIndex);

            // Number of columns to track
            int columns = 3;

            // Build sort string
            int[] array = _stack.Distinct().ToArray();
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
            {
                int i = array[index];
                if (index >= columns)
                {
                    break;
                }

                DataGridViewColumn gridViewColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[i];
                string sort = null;
                switch (gridViewColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection)
                {
                    case SortOrder.None:
                    case SortOrder.Ascending:
                        sort = "ASC";
                        break;
                    case SortOrder.Descending:
                        sort = "DESC";
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
                builder.AppendFormat("{0} {1}, ", gridViewColumn.Name, sort);
            }
            string s = builder.ToString();
            s = s.Remove(s.Length - 2);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...Not sure if this applies to my situation, but I will look at it shortly.