# How to sort more then once on my DataGridView?

Tags: c#

I am doing a project where I need to sort My data grid by priority in descending order after I click block button.   Once Block is Clicked the priority in that row changes from whatever the number is to -1 which should move it to the bottom of the grid and push the highest priority value to the top of the grid.  It works the first time I click the block button but after that nothing else responds to Any clicks of the buttons Ready or Block. I want to move all block items to the bottom of the list with -1 values and then return all the items to there proper rank in the grid after I click ready.  Can someone explain why it only sorts my grid on the first click of the delete button?

```
 namespace Dispatcher_2._0
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            DataTable Table = new DataTable();            

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }   

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Table.Columns.Add("PID", typeof(int));
                Table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
                Table.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(int));
                Table.Rows.Add(91, "Current Process", 0);
                Table.Rows.Add(92, "Ready", 23);
                Table.Rows.Add(95, "Ready", 22);
                Table.Rows.Add(93, "Ready", 28);
                Table.Rows.Add(94, "Ready", 44);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;
                DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn1 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn2 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

                Btn.Name = "Ready";
                Btn.Text = "Ready";

                Btn1.Name = "Block";
                Btn1.Text = "Block";

                Btn2.Name = "Terminate";
                Btn2.Text = "Terminate";
                Btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                Btn1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                Btn2.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn);
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn1);  
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn2);

            }

            private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Table.Clear();     
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    Table.Rows.Add(91, "Current Process", 0);
                    Table.Rows.Add(92, "Ready", 23);
                    Table.Rows.Add(95, "Ready", 22);
                    Table.Rows.Add(93, "Ready", 28);
                    Table.Rows.Add(94, "Ready", 44);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;
                }
                else { }

                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }

            private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                int selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
                string value1 = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[selectedRow].FormattedValue.ToString();

                if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Ready")
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[1].Value = "Ready";
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Block")
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[1].Value = "Blocked";
                    dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value = "-1";
                    DataView Tab = new DataView(Table);
                    Tab.Sort = "Priority desc";
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = Tab;
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Terminate")
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               Table.Rows.Add(new Random().Next(50, 100), "Ready", textBox1.Text);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891390/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-by-2-columns

Comment: wow thanks that worked quite well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort a datagridview by 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891390/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-by-2-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I have always simply filled in my tables without using a data source so I'm not exactly sure how this works.  However, I think I see your problem anyway--it sounds like you need to write a custom comparison function to sort the table with.  This is necessary any time you have data that must be sorted based on multiple columns.