# DataGridView order selected rows on top of the table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I want to reorder my DataTable in the DataGridView by the selected rows which should be inserted on top of the DataTable.-

How it looks before I order the rows:
[image: before sort selected rows]

And how it should look after I ordered them:
[image: after sort selected rows]

I tried it with followed code but it is very slow due to I am using a for loop on every single row in the DataTable:

```
if (MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
   int count = MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
   DataTable tempTableDataSource = new DataTable();

   int selectorCounter = 0;

   tempTableDataSource = (DataTable)(MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.DataSource);
   tempTableClone = tempTableDataSource.Clone();

   for (int i = 0; i < MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      if (MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected == true)
      //first add all selected rows to get them on top
      {
         DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows[i].DataBoundItem).Row;
         tempTableClone.ImportRow(dr);
         selectorCounter++;
      }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      if (MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected == false)        
      //second add all unselected rows to get them below the selected
      {
         DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows[i].DataBoundItem).Row;
         tempTableClone.ImportRow(dr);
      }
   }

   MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.DataSource = tempTableClone;

   for (int i = 0; i < selectorCounter; i++)
   {

     MainWindow.table_G_Level_Data.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
   }
}
```

unfortunately there is neither a methode to just order the selected rows on top nor the indexes can be changed due to read-only. Maybe someone has a good idea to help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add some hidden column (named lets say "Selected")
2. Set its value to "1" (or anything suitable to you) on selecting the row
3. Order/Sort on that column and `Splitter1` column using `DataGridView.Sort(...)` method.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891559/5779732) to see how to sort on multiple columns.

Comment: nice idea! 
then I can hide this column with: 
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["flagColumn"].Visible = false;