# Query About sorting specific rows of datagridveiw in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have a grid view in which i have days in one column time in another column and other data in other columns. I sorted grid with days column with sort method which sort whole grid that's fine and give me desired output but the problem is that i want further sorting grid view with time column also.

**For Example**:
I want to sort all rows which have "Monday" in days field with time column that means i want to sort all "Monday" rows only with time column and days rows as "Monday" *rows*.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sort a datagridview by 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891390/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-by-2-columns)

Comment: It is easier to sort by the Datasource.  If you have a datetime object then sort by Day Of Week.

Comment: @jdweng In my case I can't use Datasource property of datagridview any other solution?

Comment: @Cid No this is not perfect for me.

Comment: Do a search on the search for : datagridview sort.  He is one example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort?view=netframework-4.8